# Does the new fee-based priority execution model guarantee higher fees generated?

Tags: transactions, validator, fees, node

The fee-based priority execution model was recently introduced to Solana (https://decrypt.co/103106/solana-new-gas-fees), which introduces 'local' fee markets for transactions instead of a single global fee market (like Ethereum)

The question I had was, will this always lead to an increase in fees for the validator nodes as opposed to a single global fee market?

The calculation for fee in a global fee market I did was:

Fee = max_fee(t1, t2,...tn)

i.e the maximum fees of one of n transactions competing for inclusion in a block

For a local fee market, it would be,

Fee = max_fee_local_1(t1...,tn)+max_fee_local_2(t1...,
tm)+...

essentially a sum of the maximum fees of each local market.

Are these calculations correct and will this model always lead to an increase in fees? If yes, are there any more resources/tools where I can quantify this? Thank you.